# Help with finding value of exponents?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Find the value of n:

$54=2^n*3^{n+2}$

I don't know where to start. can we times 2 and 3 and get $6^{2n+2}$ ?

Comment: You can test your last question.  Try it with $n=1$ and see if you get the same thing before and after.

Comment: $54 = 2\times 27$ and guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that $ \ a^{n+2} \ = \ a^n \ \cdot \ a^2 \ . $  You can write the right-hand side of your equation as $ \ 2^n \ \cdot \ 3^n \ \cdot \ 3^2 \ .  $  And you *can* say that  $ \ 2^n \ \cdot \ 3^n \ = \ (2 \cdot 3)^n \ = \ 6^n \ . $

Comment: Right, I forgot that $a^{n+2} = a^n ⋅ a^2$ Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

$$54=2^n*3^{n+2}=2^n*3^n*3^2=9(2^n*3^n)$$
$$\implies 6=2^n*3^n=(2*3)^n=6^n$$
$$\implies n=log_6(6)= 1$$

Comment: Oops, thanks for the edit, John!

Answer (score 0):

You know because the number (54) is so low that the value of n will also be a relatively low number. You also know that 54 is 27 * 2, and 27 is 3^3.